# Trying to remove an axis below x-axis using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to `ggplot` and is trying to plot two lines using it. But my x-axis appeared to be very weird, and now i want to remove it. Here is my code.

```
ggplot(BJ11, aes(Date, mean,group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "stateair daily values")) + 
  geom_line(data = bjvalue2,
            aes(color = "CNEMC values"))
```

[image: my ggplot]

Here are my data:

```
> head(BJ11)  
       Date   min    max      mean  
1 2015-01-01   6    154  54.58333  
2 2015-01-02  12    157  63.54167  
3 2015-01-03 147    322 209.25000  
4 2015-01-04 106    360 201.16667  
5 2015-01-05   9    186  90.87500  
6 2015-01-06  10    121  43.16667


> head(bjvalue2)  
        Date     mean  
1 2015-01-01   43  
2 2015-01-02   52  
3 2015-01-03  150  
4 2015-01-04  176  
5 2015-01-05      92  
6 2015-01-06   40
```

what should i do to remove both the thick black axis above "Date" and the x-axis?

Comment: Add the following to your plot `theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_blank())`

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Comment: should put as an answer @NColl if it fixes the issue so it's easier to see in future

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(BJ11, aes(Date, mean, group=1))+
  geom_line(aes(color = "stateair daily values"))+ 
  geom_line(data = bjvalue2, aes(color = "CNEMC values"))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
      axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
      axis.line.x = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to fix your x-axis instead of removing it. I know it is not your question, but ggplot is very good in handling date-axis, so I'm wondering if you have dates as characters? If you have then eg. library(lubridate) with ymd() can be used.

I'm guessing your group=1 could be omitted for simplicity.

Also, in your last line I'd personally prefer defining the x and y axis inside the aes to make sure R handles the data the way you want.